# Is there any way to have artifacts saved for Stopped builds in AWS Codebuild?

Tags: aws-codebuild, aws-codeartifact

In AWS Codebuild, I would like the ability to upload artifacts and/or run the ability to run a command no matter the situation (like a `finally` clause). The documentation doesn't specify anything about running or saving artifacts unconditionally (the only information I have read is regarding `Failed` builds, not `Stopped` builds).

I need this ability in the case that a build gets locked up and has to be terminated or a build has to be manually stopped.

---

I have tried adding a `on_build_failure` section to my `buildspec.yml` as well as making certain that the artifact exists and is present in the `artifacts -> files` section of the `buildspec`.